# need to load a component in a panel using javascript file

Tags: templates, ember.js, handlebars.js, components, ember-cli

I have a component containing  panels, each panel should contain an existing component. I am using `handlebars.registerPartial` but it's not working.

How should I load an existing component via javascript file? I'm using `handlebars.compile` for templating each panel.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function dynamicHandlbar(params/*, hash*/) {

    var obj=params[0];
    var line=params[1];
    var template = Handlebars.compile(line);
    var partial=Handlebars.registerPartial('component', '{{CompName}}');
    var htmlContent = template(obj);
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(htmlContent);
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(dynamicHandlbar);
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem correctly but I think the built in component helper in Ember solves your problem. See: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_component

Comment: thank you it works